# False positive validation error "your post does not match quality standards” when question is in Cyrillic

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This is probably a SE bug related to Cyrillic (not being /A-Za-z/). It creates a lot of trouble for [Ukrainian.SE](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) community. See the [discussion on Meta.Ukrainian.SE](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/39/36).

Here's the steps to reproduce:

1. Enter the subject "Перевірка того, що в тексті запитання мусять бути латинські літери".
2. Enter the body:

> ```
> Чи можна писати ініціали (поруч із прізвищем) разом чи потрібно ставити пробіл між ім'ям та по батькові?` 
>
> Наприклад,
>
> > Л.П. Косач
>
> чи
>
> > Л. П. Косач
>
> Чи є правило, яке це регулює?
> ```

3. Enter the tag "bug".
4. Hit the "Post your Answer", get the "Your post doesn't match..." error message.
5. Replace the "Чи є правило, яке це регулює?" with "Do we have a rule for that?", post again and everything is fine.

The error message is very confusing, because step #5 doesn't change the question *meaning*, it's just a translation from Ukrainian to English (which coincidentally makes validator happy).

Comment: Why are you posting Ukrainian question here on Meta Stack Exchange? We don't accept Ukrainian here (or any language that is non English). Why do you think this is a bug then?

Comment: @Oded  sorry, forgot to add links to Ukr.SE. If this bug should be discussed only on Meta.Ukr, how can we escalate it to support team?

Comment: You don't need to escalate it - posting it as a bug there will get to the team. We monitor bugs on all meta sites, not just this one.

Comment: @Oded  OK, sorry for the noise

Answer (score 3):

The title and the body of the question are quite short.

I would expect them to indeed trigger the quality controls - I don't see this as a bug, but [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: But why then would translating one line to English (on a non-English(?) site) make a difference?

Comment: Could have been enough to nudge the checks into OK.

Comment: Fair enough; the English was one word more I guess...